# How to load selected months dates only by selecting month in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to load selected months dates only in datepicker. The selected month is getting from selecting month and year only datepicker.

```
$('#Month').datepicker({  //Month is the textbox to change and select month and year.
                autoclose: true,
                format: "MM yyyy",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months"
            })         
            $('#FromDate').datepicker({ //From and To date to display dates only for the month selected from Month text box.
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
           $('#ToDate').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
```

`Month` **is the textbox to change and select month and year.**

`From and To date` **to display dates only for the month selected from Month text box.**

after I selecting month and year, the value I got in text box is in **'August 2019'**(for example:) - this format. Using this value, How to set Min and max dates values.

The following function for onchange of Month text box, `Onchange= "MonthDatePick();"`

```
function MonthDatePick(){
       var month = $('#Month').val("MM/yyyy");
       //month = month.format("MM/yyyy");
       var minDate = new Date(month.getFullYear(), month.getMonth(), +1); //one day next before month
       var maxDate = new Date(month.getFullYear(), month.getMonth() + 2, +0); // one day before next month
       $( "#FromDate" ).datepicker({ 
            minDate: minDate, 
            maxDate: maxDate 
            });
   }
```

This one I tried from One of the stack overflow answer, but as my value is in Variable, cannot able to get fullyear() or fullMonth() funtion. 
How to fix this.Seniors Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var date = new Date();
var MaxDate= new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/11604356/abdulazeez-olanrewaju sir, this new Date() gives us current date right? ,but I am trying to get min and max date as first and last date of selected month and year, let's say my month chosen as March 2018 means, My from date and to date must display march 2018 month dates only